# How to populate a second select menu based on the first selection and third based on second - Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I need to display three select menus for selecting State, District and Area. In which the Second select menu should be populated dynamically based on the first and third based on the second.

For this,
I found one at [Javascriptsource.com](http://www.javascriptsource.com/forms/country-state-city-drop-down-list.html) and replaced a little to get the following,

```
    <script>


    var districts = new Array();

    districts['Tamilnadu'] = new Array('Chennai','Coimbatore','Vellore');
    districts['Andhra Pradesh'] = new Array('Hyderabad','Andra 2','Andra 3');

    var cities = new Array();

    areas['Tamilnadu'] = new Array();
    areas['Tamilnadu']['Chennai'] = new Array('Kolathur','Perambur');
    areas['Tamilnadu']['Coimbatore'] = new Array('Combatore 1','Coimbatore 2');
    areas['Tamilnadu']['Vellore'] = new Array('Vellore 1','Vellore 2');

    areas['Andhra Pradesh'] = new Array();
    areas['Andhra Pradesh']['Hyderabad'] = new Array('Hyde 1','Hyde 2');
    areas['Andhra Pradesh']['Andra 2'] = new Array('Andra2 1','Andra2 2');
    areas['Andhra Pradesh']['Andra 3'] = new Array('Andra3 1','Andra3 2');

    function setDistrict() {
    stateSelect = document.getElementById('state');
    districtList = districts[stateSelect.value];
    changeSelect('district', districtList, districtList);
    setArea();
    }

    function setArea() {
    stateSelect = document.getElementById('state');
    districtSelect = document.getElementById('district');
    areaList = areas[stateSelect.value][districtSelect.value];
    changeSelect('area', areaList, areaList);
    }

    function changeSelect(fieldID, newOptions, newValues) {
    selectField = document.getElementById(fieldID);
    selectField.options.length = 0;
     for (i=0; i<newOptions.length; i++) {
     selectField.options[selectField.length] = new Option(newOptions[i], newValues[i]);
     }
    }

    // The below codes do what?

    function addLoadEvent(func) {
    var oldonload = window.onload;
     if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
     window.onload = func;
     } else {
     window.onload = function() {
     if (oldonload) {
      oldonload();
     }
    func();
       }
      }
    }

    addLoadEvent(function() {
      setDistrict();
    });


    </script>
```

And it works fine except the third select menu does not get populated when the second select menu's value change.

What is wrong there and i also like to know whether this works on all major browsers or not?

Is there any better solution for this?
and can anyone explain what the last block of code(after the comment line) actually do?

Thanks in advance.

[ I did searching for the answer both here in stackoverflow and in other places. But nothing seems to be helpful for this need of using just javascript. ]

[UPDATE] It is working now. But will it work on all browsers and can anyone explain me what the code after the *comment line* do?

Comment: Was `var cities = new Array();` meant to be `var areas = new Array();`? I don't see you declaring `areas` anywhere, or using `cities` anywhere.

Comment: damn!
yes it should be areas not cities. Thank you, i'll check it out.

Comment: it is working now, but will it work the same way on all browsers..?

Comment: I think I've fully answered the question now, sorry I missed the bit initially about the `onload` stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues there.

1. It looks like the main issue is that you're not declaring `areas` anywhere; you're declaring `cities` instead.
2. The code is also suffering from [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) by not declaring its variables.
3. Even when declaring its variables, the code is making them globals. There's no need for that here, it's better to wrap the whole thing in a scoping function to avoid conflicts in the (very crowded) global namespace. It looks like you must be using `changeSelect` in an HTML `onXyz` attribute somewhere, so we have to do something to make it global (the better answer would be not to use HTML `onXyz` attributes, but instead use `attachEvent` (IE8 and earlier) or `addEventListener` (all others) on the `select` elements in code (I haven't tried to do that below, I just made `changeSelect` global).
4. The code where you've asked "The below codes [sic] do what?" is trying to wait to call `setDistrict` until after the `select` elements defined by the HTML exist. But that code is **very** out of date. In the mid 1990s, if you wanted to run a function when the page was done loading, you assigned it to `window.onload` or put it in the opening `<body>` tag as `<body onload="functionName();">`. There could only be **one** of these, if you did it again, it removed the first. So that code is *trying* to see if there's already one there, and if there is, replace it with the new one but also call it.

   Fortunately, in the late 90's Microsoft introduced `attachEvent` in IE 5.5 (5.0?) and soon thereafter we had DOM2 Events which gave us `addEventListener` in all other browsers, both of which let us do the same thing without removing any previous handler.

   But there's no need to wait for the `window` `load` event here, and it's a bad idea because it doesn't fire until after **everything** loads, including all of your images. Instead, we just put the `script` element with this code at the very end of your HTML, just before the closing `</body>` tag, and call `setDistrict()` directly:

   ```
   // Just make sure this script is referenced from a `script` element
   // at the **end** of the HTML, just before the closing `</body>` tag
   setDistrict();
   ```

   The elements will exist at that point. No reason to wait any longer than that (and `window.onload` is a lot later).
5. Neither `districts` nor `areas` (or some of the `area` sub-elements) should be arrays. They're not being used as arrays at all, just as objects. All of that initialization of `districts` and `areas` can be *much* simpler.

Do putting all of that together, with some proper formatting:

```
// Scoping function prevents the `vars` inside from being globals
(function() {
    // Create our districts and areas
    var districts = {
        "Tamilnadu": ["Chennai", "Coimbatore", "Vellore"],
        "Andhra Pradesh": ["Hyderabad", "Andra 2", "Andra 3"]
    };

    var areas = {
        "Tamilnadu": {
            "Chennai": ["Kolathur", "Perambur"],
            "Coimbatore": ["Combatore 1", "Coimbatore 2"],
            "Vellore": ["Vellore 1", "Vellore 2"]
        },

        "Andhra Pradesh": {
            "Hyderabad": ["Hyde 1", "Hyde 2"],
            "Andra 2": ["Andra2 1", "Andra2 2"],
            "Andra 3": ["Andra3 1", "Andra3 2"]
        }
    };

    function setDistrict() {
        // Note the use of `var` to make these variables local to the function
        var stateSelect = document.getElementById('state');
        var districtList = districts[stateSelect.value];
        changeSelect('district', districtList, districtList);
        setArea();
    }

    function setArea() {
        // Note the use of `var` to make these variables local to the function
        var stateSelect = document.getElementById('state');
        var districtSelect = document.getElementById('district');
        var areaList = areas[stateSelect.value][districtSelect.value];
        changeSelect('area', areaList, areaList);
    }

    // Make `changeSelect` available globally
    window.changeSelect = changeSelect;
    function changeSelect(fieldID, newOptions, newValues) {
        // Note the use of `var` to make these variables local to the function
        var i;
        var selectField = document.getElementById(fieldID);
        selectField.options.length = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < newOptions.length; i++) {
            selectField.options[selectField.length] = new Option(newOptions[i], newValues[i]);
        }
    }

    // Make sure this script is at the *end* of the HTML, just above the
    // closing </body> tag
    setDistrict();
})();
```

---

Side note: When talking about programming code, the word "code" is a "mass noun" like "water". It's never plural. So it's always "this code" not "these codes."

Comment: @tjcrowder Thanks...Can you say what the code after the comment line actually do...? For what purpose it is there...?

Comment: @Saravanan: I'll add an explanation to the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I hope i got all your answers but finally just one more question, whether the code is compatible in all browsers or..?

Comment: @Saravanan: Yup, as far as I know that method of updating `options` works across the board.

Comment: @Saravanan: FYI, I realized you must be calling `changeSelect` from an HTML `onChange` attribute or similar. If so, putting the code in a scoping function will break that. I've updated the code in the answer (you may want to hit refresh) so that it makes `changeSelect` global. It's not the best answer, but going further involves changing things even more, and we've probably already spent enough time. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me with this. I hope people searching for this **code** may find this useful.